# oracle DB url required for hosting java code

Tags: java, oracle, hosting

While we host Java code in localhost usually we use:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.
            getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "system", "password");
```

but when we will host in hosting servers with IP address then how can we configure URL.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `localhost` with the name/IP of the server..